# Node + Mysql - Issue with connection

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, mean-stack

I do some mistake with connecting mysql in express which i couldn't figure out. 
The basic connection code below works well.

```
 var connection = mysql.createConnection({
      host     : 'localhost',
      user:'root',
      password:'',
      database :'testdb'
    });
    connection.connect();
    connection.query('SELECT * from test2table', function (err, data) {
      if (err) throw err

     console.log('The solution is: '+JSON.stringify(data)); -->could obtain data
    });
```

But when it comes to use  inside a get/post method , i donot get a response. Like code below:

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host : 'localhost',
  user:'root',
  password:'',
  database :'testdb'
});
connection.connect(function(err){
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log("connected");
    });



 app.get('/api/records',function(req,res){
        connection.query('SELECT * from test2table', function (err, data) {
            console.log(data);--> get blank response
    });
 });
```

Please let me know if i missed anything inbetween which affects. Thankyou.

Comment: try to figure out what that err variable contains

Comment: it throws no error :-/

Comment: Yes it will not, but the point is to check what it contains, use `console.log(err) ` for better understanding.

Comment: It neither produce error nor retrieve data. i have an insert query next to select and that insert api is working so well! ain't sure why not select.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with app.locals?

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host : 'localhost',
  user:'root',
  password:'',
  database :'testdb'
});
connection.connect(function(err){
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log("connected");
});

app.locals.connection = connection;
app.get('/api/records',function(req,res){
        app.locals.connection.query('SELECT * from test2table', function (err, data) {
            console.log(data);--> get blank response
    });
 });
```

See more details here: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.locals

Comment: thumbs down. behavior is still the same.

Comment: The fun part is, I even perform insert query with same structure i use for select and that works well. ain't sure why not select.