# Select not working with node-mysql but insert does.

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, mean-stack

I have been trying to perform insert operation that takes form data to mysql db and then selection operation to fetch data from db.The get method api would be called first since records of table would get populated on client on load. The problem is insert operation works pretty well but select operation doesn't.It neither responds with error nor a value.
The code is:

```
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
      host : '***',
      user:'***',
      password:'***',
      database :'***'
    });
connection.connect();
app.get('/records',function(req,res){
   connection.query('SELECT * from test2table', function (err,rows) {
  console.log(err);

  console.log('The solution is: '+JSON.stringify(rows)); 
});
   });
app.post('/records',function(req,res){

    connection.query('INSERT INTO test2table (id,name,place) VALUES (NULL,'gg','trivandrum')',function(err,res){
        console.log("written");
    });
});
```

I did a random search on related issues and i find async having impact on it. I ain't sure how to solve. Please favour.

Comment: what is the error did you got? or did you try with promises?

Comment: @Gayathri what you r actually doing?? First get request to retrieve all data from test2table to show the contents in front-end, and they posting new data to test2table??? Whats the problem??

Comment: Might have chances that record inserted not available immediately , But you need to give more detail . @Gayathri

Comment: @MohideenibnMohammed I don't get any errors. I just don't get any response. Even console.log(rows) don't show me the data in table.

Comment: @Subburaj  All i try is, fill form details -> submit -> get stored in DB -> on refresh, load table data and show table data on webpage. 
Till storing data in DB, all works fine. And i have data in db too. But select query is unresponsive and i ain't sure why. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45445542/node-mysql-issue-with-connection for the same.

Comment: @Sumeet Data is already available in table as well. Please refer my previous comment.

Comment: @Gayathri Your above code looks fine, my guess is that the way u r calling get request may be the problem,, Can you post the full code and explain litte but more , so that we can get an idea..